# Не работает Форма обратной связи на Ajax (в php)

Tags: ajax

Ребята, помогите решить ребус. Есть LP, в котором есть Форма обратной связи, выплывает в модальном окне, через кнопку. На обычной верстке все работает нормально, а после натяжки на WP - заполняешь форму -> нажимаешь Отправить, и ничего не происходит!!! Файл Contact.php лежит в корне темы (/wp-content/themes/mysite). Может я неправильно путь указываю к coctact.php?

Файл - home.php

```html
<!-- Modal window -->
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="close_modal">
            <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
        </div>
        <form class="fofm" id="fofm" action="/contact.php" method="POST">
            <h5>Форма<span>заявки</span></h5>
            <div class="logo logo-modal d-flex">
                <img class="logo-img" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/./img/page1/logo.png" alt="logo">
                
            </div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="| Имя" name="txtname" required=""><i class="fas fa-user modal-user"></i>
            <input type="email" placeholder="| E-mail" name="txtemail" required=""><i class="fas fa-envelope modal-envelope"></i>
            <input type="tel" placeholder="| Tелефон" pattern="^([\+]+)*[0-9\x20\x28\x29\-]{5,20}$" name="txtphone"><i class="fas fa-phone modal-phone"></i>
            <textarea type="text" placeholder="| Cообщение" name="txtmessage" rows="10" required=""></textarea><i class="fas fa-sms modal-sms"></i>
            
            <label><input type="checkbox">я не </label><i class="fas fa-robot modal-robot"></i>
            <input type="hidden" name="valTrFal" class="valTrFal" value="valTrFal_disabled">
            <input type="submit" class="button" value="Отправить" disabled="disabled" name="btnsend">
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- window after "send" -->
    <div class="popup2">
    <div class="close_modal">
        <i class="far fa-times-circle"></i>
    </div>
        <div class="window">
            <div class="insText">
                <h5>Форма<span>заявки</span></h5>
                <p><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory') ?>/img/green_icon.png"><strong>Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!</strong><p>
                <hr>
                <p>В ближайшее время<br>я свяжусь с вами!</p>
                <hr>
                <div class="modal-popup2">C уважением,<br>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-popup2-footer">
                    <p>&#169; Copyright 2018-2019 | 
                        
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Файл - main.js

```js
// ----- Modal window ----- //

  //в этой функции отслеживается изменение чекбокса "я не робот"
    $(document).on('change', '.fofm input:checkbox', function() {
      if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $(".fofm input[type=submit]").removeAttr('disabled');
        $('.fofm input[type=hidden].valTrFal').val('valTrFal_true');
      }
      else {
        $(".fofm input[type=submit]").attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('.fofm input[type=hidden].valTrFal').val('valTrFal_disabled');
      }
    });

    //закрытие модального окна
    $('.close_modal, .overlay').click(function (){
      $('.popup, .popup2, .overlay').css({'opacity':'0', 'visibility':'hidden'});
      $('.popup > .fofm textarea').val('');
      //сброс всех полей формы обраной связи
      $(':input','.fofm').not(':button, :submit, :reset, :hidden').val('').removeAttr('checked').removeAttr('selected');
      $(".fofm input[type=submit]").attr('disabled','disabled');
    });

    //показ модального окна
    $('.open_modal').click(function (e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $('.popup, .overlay').css({'opacity':'1', 'visibility':'visible'});
    });

    //аякс форма обратной связи
    //проверяет какой ответ был получен
    //и в зависимости от ответа
    //выводит информацию о статусе
    //отправки письма
    $("#fofm").submit(function() {
      var str = $(this).serialize();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/contact.php",
        data: str,
        success: function(msg) {
          if(msg == 'ok') {
            $('.popup2, .overlay').css('opacity','1');
            $('.popup2, .overlay').css('visibility','visible');
            $('.popup').css({'opacity':'0','visibility':'hidden'});
          }
          else {
            $('.popup2 .window').html('<h5>Ошибка</h5><p>Сообщение не отправлено, убедитесь в правильности заполнение полей</p>');
            $('.popup2, .overlay').css('opacity','1');
            $('.popup2, .overlay').css('visibility','visible');
            $('.popup').css({'opacity':'0','visibility':'hidden'});
          }
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
```

Файл - contact.php

```php
<?php
//проверяем значения полученые при проверке скриптом формы
if (trim($_POST['valTrFal'])!='valTrFal_true') {
    echo 'fasle';
}
else {

        $txtname = trim($_POST['txtname']);

        $txtNameValue = trim($_POST['name_class_value']);

        $txtemail = trim($_POST['txtemail']);

        $txtphone = trim($_POST['txtphone']);

        $txtmessage = trim($_POST['txtmessage']);

        // от кого
        $fromMail = 'web@gmail.com';
        $fromName = 'denis';

        // Сюда введите Ваш email
        $emailTo = 'web@gmail.com';

        $subject = 'Форма обратной связи';
        $subject = '=?utf-8?b?'. base64_encode($subject) .'?=';
        $headers = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=\"utf-8\"\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: ". $fromName ." <". $fromMail ."> \r\n";

        // тело письма
        $body = "Получено письмо с сайта www.com\n\nИмя: $txtname\nТелефон: $txtphone\ne-mail: $txtemail \nСообщение: $txtmessage";
        $mail = mail($emailTo, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f'. $fromMail );


        echo 'ok';
}
?>
```

Comment: И еще забыл написать...вначале загружается "Прелоадер" и библиотека jQuery 3.3.1 - Возможна это играет роль в решении моей проблемы...

Answer (score 0):

Решение такое:
Да, действительно ошибка была в адресе. В файле - main.js
Нужно было прописать так: 
type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-content/themes/mysite/contact.php",
        data: str,